# Format Twilio's date format ( Wed, 21 Oct 2015 19:19:53 +0000 ) into timestamp

Tags: php, date, twilio, twilio-php

I've been trying to convert Twilio's convoluted time format **(Wed, 21 Oct 2015 19:19:53 +0000)** into timestamp so I can format it into something more digestible in PHP. I've tried various methods but none works.

Can somebody please shed some light?

Answer (score 5):

Just use `DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $timestring)`, then call `getTimestamp()` on the object it returns:

```
$datetime = DateTime::createFromFormat("D, j M Y G:i:s O", "Wed, 21 Oct 2015 19:19:53 +0000");
//or $datetime = DateTime::createFromFormat("(D, j M Y G:i:s O)", "(Wed, 21 Oct 2015 19:19:53 +0000)");
$timestamp = $datetime->getTimestamp();
```

And actually, it looks like it is `DateTime::RFC1123` format, so you can just do:

```
$datetime = DateTime::createFromFormat(DateTime::RFC1123, "Wed, 21 Oct 2015 19:19:53 +0000");
```